# Google App Engine: Region set to United States but requests seem to be routed to Japan?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have created a simple application which collects Google search results, deployed it on App Engine, and set the region to 'us-central'.

However, when I send a request to the application, the results seem to be based in Japan (e.g., when searching 'news', the results are news companies based in Japan).

I have tested the application locally and results are based in my region.

Any ideas on why this happens? And perhaps how to solve this?

Comment: I experienced the same thing but it doesn't matter to me so I didn't try to fix it.  Try to match the headers sent by your personal web browser.  Though it might be based on the IP address.

Comment: Google news results don't sound like a particularly accurate way to determine the way your packages are being routed tbh (not to mention routing probably has nothing to do with the region setting it guesses). The google news server might guess your request is coming from Japan for a whole bunch of reason, possibly just a public ip address that it wrongly thinks is Japanese range, I don't see why you would care?